POST request successful, GET request giving 200 code but empty array
I am a beginner and practising writing some API routes to a MySQL database. My database is being updated successfully using both the form on my application and in Postman. When I use the MySQL interface, 'select * from moods;' works and returns the tables, but my GET request is just returning an empty array (in POSTMAN and frontend) and giving the 200 OK code.
router.get("/", async function(req, res) {
  // Fetch all emotrack entries from the database
  try {
    let results = await db(`SELECT * FROM moods;`);
    if (results.data.length === 0) {
      console.log("no data found in moods")
    }
    res.status(200).send(results.data);
    console.log(results)
  } catch(err) {
    console.error('Database query failed:', err); // Log the error for debugging
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'Internal Server Error', details: err.message });
  }
});
  
// getting 'no data found in moods' logged on the console


router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const text = req.body;
    const sql = `INSERT INTO moods (mood, intensity, triggers) VALUES('${text.mood}', '${text.intensity}', '${text.triggers};');`;
    await db(sql);
    const result = await db("SELECT * FROM moods;");
    res.status(201).send(result.data);
    console.log(result.data)
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});

// this works fine

My course that I did wrote us a db() function to use MySQL and I think that this is working as it works fine with my POST request so I don't think it would be that.
require("dotenv").config();
const mysql = require("mysql2");

module.exports = async function db(query, values) {
  const results = {
    data: [],
    error: null
  };

  let promise = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const DB_HOST = process.env.DB_HOST;
    const DB_USER = process.env.DB_USER;
    const DB_PASS = process.env.DB_PASS;
    const DB_NAME = process.env.DB_NAME;

    const con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: DB_HOST || "127.0.0.1",
      user: DB_USER || "root",
      password: DB_PASS,
      database: DB_NAME || "mood_tracker",
      multipleStatements: true
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err); // Consistent error logging
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log("Connected!");

      con.query(query, values, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          results.error = err;
          console.log(err); // Consistent error logging
          reject(err);
          return;
        }

        if (!result.length) {
          if (result.affectedRows === 0) {
            results.error = "Action not complete";
            console.log(results.error); // Consistent error logging
            reject(results.error);
            return;
          }
          // Commented out as it is not necessary
          // results.data.push(result);
        } else if (result[0].constructor.name == "RowDataPacket") {
          result.forEach(row => results.data.push(row));
        } else if (result[0].constructor.name == "OkPacket") {
          results.data.push(result[0]);
        }

        resolve(results);
      });
    })
  });

  return promise;
};

I do know that I just updated from MySQL -> MySQL2 so I'm not sure if that changes anything here?
Let me know if you need any more info for debugging.

We don't know what db() is or does.  And while we can certainly guess, if you're telling us that you "know it works" and that it's "returning an empty array" then what you're telling us is that an empty array is the correct result that you expect?  Additionally, while the SQL injectable code may not be the problem, it certainly isn't helping.  It's not really clear what we can do to help without more debugging on your part.

I understand, sorry @David I'm new here and might have underestimated what was required on my part! I am updating my question now

@jabaa the course I did used this db function and didn't explain much else for us to easily start writing API routes to MySQL databases. Great in theory except none of us therefore understood how it worked. Maybe I would be better off scrapping the db function and just writing normal queries

Start the code in your debugger and step through the db function. Where does the empty array come from and  why is it empty? This course is about advanced topics like network and databases. I assume, it's common sense, that you already know JavaScript, Node.js and debugging. If not, it's probably the wrong course for you.

FYI you're supposed to parameterise your query, and pass the values in separately (as the second argument to your db() function), so that you don't leave your code open for SQL Injection attacks - or just silly syntax errors...someone could break your INSERT query right now just by putting an apostrophe (') in one of the input values! Seems this course maybe isn't teaching you the fundamentalsd properly. Either that or you haven't looked carefully enough at any provided examples.
